# [iOS]how to use NSURLConnection with a private IP address?

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection

I have an iOS app on A (iPhone), there is a computer B in the same network as A is in, and there is also a remote server C on the Internet. Originally, through NSURLConnection, I can call `GET https://domain_of_C/resources` directly from the app to get some resources on C. Now the requirement is that I need to first call B at 192.168.1.2 (B's IP address) by:`GET https://192.168.1.2/resources`, and then B should help A forward everything to C, as well as getting the response back from C to A. B should blindly pass through the packets, including the SSL packets.

Below is a code snippet:

```
NSURL *newUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://192.168.1.2/resources"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:newUrl];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2018-11-26 10:10:50.666321-0500 [72744:1796043] TIC SSL Trust Error [3:0x600002c98180]: 3:0
2018-11-26 10:10:50.667535-0500 [72744:1796043] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
2018-11-26 10:10:50.667641-0500 [72744:1796043] Task <68E602A9-1FF8-4A60-AE72-191AA1D8D730>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9843])
```

However, if I use http://192.168.1.2/resources as the URL(HTTP here, not HTTPS), it works, meaning that I can successfully access the resources on the remote server from A. The design of B is that it should blindly pass through everything to C, including SSL session, which means that I don't hope to deal with SSL certificates at all.

I don't exactly know why iOS is throwing error in this case but I want to know if there is any way that i can avoid this error.

Comment: HTTPS URLs with only IP addresses and not hostnames, are not a good idea. First it will be difficult (but not completely impossible) to get proper X.509 certificates with an IP address in them instead of a domain name. Then at the OS/webserver level it means you are wasting a given IP for only one HTTPS service as you will not be able to have others due to the lack of SNI. As for generic TCP/TLS proxy, have a look at HAProxy, nginx, or pound.

Comment: B can't be "blindly passing everything...including the SSL session" since you have opened an https connection to B. To get the pass through you described, B would need to be acting as an http proxy (using the `CONNECT` directive) or acting as a Socks proxy (which again would require specific socksified code in your iOS app). You are getting -1202 which indicates that the certificate from B is not trusted.  If B did somehow use the same certificate as A then would would get a certificate subject error since what you have is a MITM.  TLS is designed to prevent what you are doing